# Internet Explorer 11 Developer Tools Breakpoints pane missing

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm on Windows 10 using IE 11. I'm in the process of debugging a JavaScript and somehow the Callstack/Breakpoints pane (lower right) on the Debugger tab went missing.
The Micorsoft page states it should be there but I don't see how I could have disabled it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255007(v=vs.85).aspx
Is there a key combination I randomly might have pressed in error?

Answer (score 3):

Seems I maximized the variables watche pane and dragged the callstack/breakpoints pane to the very bottom of the debugger window so it seemed gone.